# Unexpected EOF While Parsing : self.+widgetName+.text()

Tags: python, pyqt4, eof

I am trying to create an autoconnector for the signal/slot connection for Qwidgets but I'm getting an Unexepcted EOF While Parsing error. I'm not familliar with this error, from what I could understand this error occurs when the body of a function/condition/loop is not provided and the interpreter feels something missing. Why does it not work with lambda : self."+widgetName+".text() ?

```
def descriptorBuffer(self, descriptor, aliases):
    """
    Generates et stores Qt connect() expressions into a buffer. 
    It uses the descriptor from config.py and the alias dictionnary from teachAll.py.
    """
    # print("descriptBuffer")
    for infos in descriptor :
        nb_infos = len(infos)
        
        widgetName = infos[self.IND_WIDGET]
        widgetClass = self.findWidgetClass(widgetName)
        paramName = infos[self.IND_PARAM]
        if paramName in aliases :
            paramName = aliases[paramName]
        
        if nb_infos <= 2 : #Version minimaliste

            try :
                signal = self.dictDefaultSignalSlot[widgetClass][0]
                slot = self.dictDefaultSignalSlot[widgetClass][1]
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error in descriptor : {}".format(e))
                continue
            
            
            print( "\tConnecting " + widgetName + " with " + paramName)
            
            #isCheckable case
            if widgetClass in {'QPushButton','QToolButton','QCheckBox','QRadioButton'} :
                Do something
            
            #sliderReleased : .value() case
            elif widgetClass in {'QSlider','QDial'} :
                Do something else
            
            #textEdit : .toPlainText() case
            #Not fixed : Set intermediary values
            elif widgetClass in {'QTextEdit'}:
                Do something else 2
                    
            #General case
            elif widgetClass in {'QSpinBox', 'QComboBox', 'QLineEdit'} :
                print("self."+widgetName+"."+signal+".connect(lambda: self."+widgetName+"."+slot+"(self."+widgetName+".text())", dict(self=self) )
                eval("self."+widgetName+"."+signal+".connect(lambda: self."+widgetName+"."+slot+"(self."+widgetName+".text())", dict(self=self) )
```

Output of the print:self.lineEdit_jointFriction_B.textChanged.connect(lambda: self.lineEdit_jointFriction_B.setText(self.lineEdit_jointFriction_B.text())

Comment: Please provide an actual [mre]. Also, you should not use `eval`, but `getattr`. Finally, it's usually better to use the object's meta object returned by `instance.metaObject()` and eventually get its signals/properties from there.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a missing parenthesis somewhere, but you shouldn't be using `eval` here. Use `getattr` to get the value of an attribute whose name is stored as a `str`.

```
widget = getattr(self, widgetName)
signal_object = getattr(widget, signal)
slot_object = getattr(widget, slot)

widget.connect(lambda: slot(widget.text()), dict(self=self))
```